# Removing event listeners for local variables?

Tags: actionscript-3, garbage-collection

Do you have to remove event listeners on variables with local scope? By this I mean...does the event listener still exist if the variable only exists as long as the function/method is running?

```
private function startSomething():void
        {
            whatever.start();
            var t:Timer = new Timer(2000,1);
            t.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, stopSomething, false, 0, true);
            t.start();
        }

private function stopSomething(e:TimerEvent):void
        {
            // do you have to remove the event listener here??

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the timer will fire only once, there is no need to remove the listener.

Comment: I do have a related question (added detail above)...if the variable only "exists" inside of the first method, do I have to worry about removing event listeners for that variable??

Comment: For timer, the event listener is valid even if the timer variable is out of scope. The timer event fires after the function execution is over and variable is out of scope. So if that is repeating then you should remove listener as the method specified in Simsoft's answer when you no longer need that. But if the timer is not repeating then there is no need. Same goes for display objects too. Say you have added a button on existing display object. The button variable is local, but as the button is present on display object that will listen the events. Hope it helps.

Comment: The variable is out of scope does not always mean that the reference is invalid. There might be other references to the object in addition to local variable. The display object containers have reference to their child. So if you create a display object with local variable, add that to a container. Then the local variable is out of scope but the container is having a reference to the child and that is valid as long as the container is valid. So the event listeners on that child are also valid in this case.

Comment: wow that explains so much, thanks. I always thought you didn't have to worry about it, guess that's where my bugs are coming from...hehe.

Answer (score 3):

If you really need to do it, you can do :

`Timer(e.currentTarget).removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, stopSomething);`

Almost all event target/currentTarget properties refers to the trigger object.

Comment: I should have written this in my answer too, just in case when the timer repeats. +1 for adding this.